# IDLE idents are 8 spaces instead of 4 - is it a syntax error?

Tags: python, indentation, python-idle

I am new to Python and I have come across a weird issue with my code. I know that this question has been asked before but I cannot seem to find any errors in my code related to the other posts.

Whenever I press [tab], there is an 8 space indent as a pose to a 4 space indent with all other documents that I have specified in options. I havn't commented my code because I think the problem is with me having an extra bracket or something similar so knowing what the code is meant to do wouldn't make much difference. Here is my code:

```
import os.path
import time

def writeLine(localFile,lines,currentLine):
    if lines==(currentLine-1):
            print("Writing document.")
            print("The document has been successfully written to.")
    else:
            writeContent = input("What would you like to write to line " + str(currentLine) + "?\n")
            currentLine = currentLine + 1
            write_doc = open(localFile, "a")
            if lines==(currentLine-1):
                    write_doc.write(writeContent)
            else:
                    write_doc.write(writeContent + "\n")
            write_doc.close()
            writeLine(localFile,lines,currentLine)

def writeDoc(localFile):
    lines = int(input("How many lines will your document have?\n"))
    currentLine = 1
    time.sleep(0.5)
    writeLine(localFile,lines,currentLine)

def checkDoc(localFile,localMode):
    print("Verifing file")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if localMode!="w":
        if os.path.isfile(localFile):
            print("The file exists. Now proceeding.")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            writeDoc(localFile)
        else:
            print("The file does not exist. Please either create the file or use the write function to create it.")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            start()

    else:
        if os.path.isfile(localFile):
            print("The file already exists. To modify the file, please use the amend function.")
            print("The  file does not exist. Creating the file.")
            time.sleep(1)
            create_doc = open(localFile, "w")
            create_doc.write("")
            create_doc.close()
            if os.path.isfile(localFile):
                print("File created successfully.")
                writeDoc(localFile)
        else:
            print("The file couldn't be created. Please ensure that...\n  a) You have full admin privileges\n  b) The file path is correct\n  c) If all else fails, try running this in an elevated session.")

def start():
    file = input("Please enter the full file path of the file you wish to use\n")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    mode = input("What would you like to do with the file, read, write, append or read/write ('r', 'w', 'a' or 'r+')\n")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    checkDoc(file,mode)
start()
```

Sorry for posting the whole thing, but I have no idea where the error is occuring. I'm sure that it's just a simple typo but no matter how much I look, I cannot find it. If anybody could let me know where I have gone wrong, that would be great!

Comment: This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with your code.

Comment: What is the error?  Post the traceback.

Comment: If its a missed bracket, running the code will gove a syntax error and point to the line with the error.

Comment: I'm not getting an error message but the indenting is messed up and I understand this can be becuase of brakets misplased.

Comment: I made a quick test of your code and it looks like it work fine, the only thing I note is that the identation level in the `if` blocks in the function `writeLine` is 8 while in the rest is 4

Comment: I just tried removing those indents and that worked great!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a fix, with help from Copperfield. I went through all of my code and removed all of the weird indents and it set back to normal. The problem probably started by me accidently pressing [tab] twice! Oops!

Thanks for all your help!
Reece Coombes